# String columns are not listing inside the metrics, only allowed to select numeric column types from the metrics while creating report in GoodData

Tags: bigdata, analytics, gooddata, cloud-connect

[image]

Hi, 
I am new in GoodData, I am trying to create a report in that I have to show the product name but inside the Matrics tab I am only allowed to chose numeric columns.
How can I show string columns in Report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to check GoodData documentation for platform beginners to get understanding about basic concepts. There is tutorial which will be good start - https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/GoodData+Developer+Tutorial. There is part for Concepts - https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Concepts and also for Creating Metrics & Reports - https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Creating+Metrics+and+Reports
In your particular case I suggest you are aiming for adding Attribute to your report, which can be achieved in "How" section.

Comment: Thanks I was selecting Metrics instead of attributes for selecting string type columns